# Accuracy and Val accuracy not equal

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, transfer-learning

[image]I am working on Covid-19 detection with pre-trained models called Resnet50 and VGG19. However, during training the accuracy increases and the validation accuracy decreases? What is the issue in my code?

```
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False,
                        weights='imagenet',
                        input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_CHANNELS))
    
base_model.trainable = False

# for layer in base_model.layers:
#     layer.trainable = False
    
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
#model.add(Dense(fc_layer, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(fc_layer,activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0005), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(3, activation="softmax"))

if verbose:
    base_model.summary()
    model.summary()
```

Comment: Hi Oxbowerce, could you help me please?

Comment: Your model probably overfits, i.e. the model is too complex for the training data. Unless you can add more training data, you should try to simplify the model.

Comment: It should not be an issue, if you train acc > val acc your model is fine, overfitting comes when you have better score on validation set than on training set. But without additonal info its hard to tell more. If you can add plots of accuracy per epoch it can help to better understand whats going on.

Comment: Yaroslaw Homenko, Thanks for your valuable response .  iam using 1200 images of each class as training. And 900 validation for each class, But the plot is not looking fine.

Comment: Thanks Erwan, iam stuck i have changed the Covid-data samples now the model is working well on Covid- But not working well on other two classes. How can i share my code? Could you have  chance to see it please? I can share you my google drive link. So possible take a chance.

Comment: I have attached the plot. Please help

Comment: @WebSol you need to use `@somebody` if you want people to be notified about your comment. I'm not expert in images so I wouldn't be able to help anyway. In general a lot depends on the data itself, not necessarily the code. Also you didn't give a lot of info about the task you're doing: how many classes, how many instances, etc. Do you have a test set? What is the performance on the test set, can you show a confusion matrix of the results?